# After rebooting the system, MariaDB does not start?

Tags: mariadb

```
Начат процесс запуска юнита mariadb.service.
апр 02 08:41:35 doox911 audit[3334]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=3334 comm="mysqld" reques
апр 02 08:41:35 doox911 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 1 callbacks suppressed
апр 02 08:41:35 doox911 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1554183695.904:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/no
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic) starting as process 3334 ...
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. S
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.13 started; log sequence number 1116402009; transaction id 3446
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: Version: '10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distri
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 audit[3334]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" nam
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1554183696.052:66): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=
апр 02 08:41:36 doox911 mysqld[3334]: 2019-04-02  8:41:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190402  8:41:36
апр 02 08:42:16 doox911 sudo[3319]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

After rebooting I do `sudo systemctl status mariadb` and see error

> /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Marmayogi I reinstalled the system and it all worked.

Comment: Edit the question and post the output  of command `locate liblz4.so.1`.  Also post output of command `mysql -V`

Comment: I am glad that you have solved your problem.